dialog not visible when migrated to angular 17
entryComponents is removed from @ngmodule as part of angular 16. We have couple of dialogs in custom library which is accessed in the MFE. After migrating to angular 17 the dialogs are not opening
Facing issue mentioned in the Screenshot of dialog DOM. When debugged the code we could see that ngOninit is not triggered in the dialog component and hence no data is getting loaded. Is there any alternative for entryComponent?
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../../../service/authentication.service';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CreateGroupDialogComponent);
  }    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-group-dialog',
  template: `
    <span>Hello World!</span>
  `
})
export class CreateGroupDialogComponent {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateGroupDialogComponent>) {  }
}

